# Sending one email with multiple attached files

Tags: excel, vba, macos, email

I'm trying to send one email with five attached files instead of five emails with five attached files.

Function to send:

```
Function SendFilesToEmail(strRecipients As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String)

    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    
    objEmail.FROM = "EMAIL"                          'Set Body for mail
    objEmail.To = strRecipients                                  'Set Recipient
    objEmail.Subject = strSubject                                'Set Subject
    objEmail.Textbody = strBody
    folderReports = "\\ FOLDER...\"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'if microsoft scripting runtime library activated not needed
    Set reportFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderReports)
    
    For Each ReportFile In reportFolder.Files
    
         If ReportFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
            fileName = folderReports & ReportFile.Name
            objEmail.AddAttachment fileName
         End If
    
    Next ReportFile
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "EMAILSERVER"
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = ..
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
    objEmail.Send
    
End Function
```

This loops through files and calls sending email:

```
Sub MakroTest()
    Dim ReportFile As Object
    Dim currentReportFile As String
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'if microsoft scripting runtime library activated not needed
    Set reportFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderReports)
    
    For Each ReportFile In reportFolder.Files
    
         If ReportFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
            currentReportFile = folderReports & ReportFile.Name
            OpenFileAsTemp ReportFile.Name, currentReportFile
            Call Test2(ReportFile.Name)
            
            Call SaveFileAndSendEmail(ReportFile.Name)
         End If
    
    Next ReportFile

End Sub
```

Sub in another module for sending email:

```
Sub SaveFileAndSendEmail(workbookName As String)
    Dim filePath As String
    Set wbk = Workbooks(workbookName)
    Dim FilePathTo As String
    
    wbk.Close True
    
    filePath = "C:\tmp\" & workbookName
    FilePathTo = "\\FOLDER" & workbookName
    
    If Dir(FilePathTo) <> "" Then Kill FilePathTo
    FileCopy filePath, FilePathTo
    SendFilesToEmail "EMAILS", "Verpackung REPORT", "Report is sent."
    
End Sub
```

This creates five emails with five files. I want one email with five files.

Answer (score 0):

The code iterates over all `.xlsx` files in a folder twice. First, you can see the loop in the `SendFilesToEmail` sub:

```
For Each ReportFile In reportFolder.Files
         If ReportFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
```

Then in the `MacroTest` sub you can find the same statements:

```
For Each ReportFile In reportFolder.Files
         If ReportFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
```

So, you need to exclude one loop from the code.